# reverting from executing chmod by mistake

Tags: permissions

I ran `sudo chmod 600 / swapfile` by mistake as it was intended to be `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile` (No space between the `/` and `swapfile`.) and
now I am getting permission denied for everything I try to do.

Is there anything i could do now? any way to reset all permissions for the system?

`ls -ld /` gives:

```
drw------- 23 root root 4096 Jul 3 11:45 /
```

[image]

`ls -l /` shows that all the other files seem to have normal privileges.

[image]

Comment: What was the exact command? `chmod 600` is not a valid command and will have failed if you tried it. `chmod 600 /swapfile` is valid, but you would have to use `sudo` in front of it for it to do anything.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /` & `and ls -l /` add them to your question.

Comment: @Jos it was chmod 600 / swapfile there was a space between / and swapfile

Comment: Still doesn't do anything unless you use `sudo`.

Comment: sorry it was with sudo, just sudo is used for all commands i dont even think about it as a command thats why i didnt mention it, my mistake =(

Comment: Permissions on `/` should be `drwxr-xr-x` or 755. Perhaps you can change it back?

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 /` as @Jos suggested should do the trick if you didn't change anything else. If it doesn't work try booting into a Live USB/CD, find the correct partition and change it from there

Comment: just did chmod 755 / checking if this done the correct thing

Comment: Yes! it worked! i was stupid enough and i thought that all files in / got the wrong permission and not only the / itself. thank you very much to every1 for this!

Comment: Good to see it worked. You would have been in real trouble if you had used the `-r` flag.

Comment: yea i would have, luckily i didnt. But got some headache anyway from it as im not particularly used to running linux and its a server for work which has some data for other servers to work.

Comment: @Jos post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did `sudo chmod 600 / swapfile` which set the permissions of `/` to `drw-------` (equivalent to 600). Luckily, you only changed the permission properties of the `/` folder and not of any underlying folders. That would have happened if you included the `-r` flag.

The default permissions of `/` are `drwxr-xr-x` (equivalent to 755). As `root`, you have write permission in `/` and therefore you can simply change the permissions back with:

`sudo chmod 755 /`

And you will have the original situation back.

The command that you accidentally ran also tried to change the permissions of the file `swapfile` in the current folder, which probably doesn't exist.